# Concavity of cumulative distribution functions

Tags: integration, convex-analysis

Let $F(x)$ a cumulative distribution function. Are there necessary and sufficient conditions on $F$ such that

$\int_{\phi-\xi}^{\phi+\xi} F(x)\frac{1}{2\xi}  dx < F(\phi)$

By inspection, if $F$ is concave the inequality is always true (and never if $F$ is convex).

Comment: I think you want $\le$ in your inequality, to include the special case where $F$ is only (weakly) concave.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the general case changing your point of view. Let $F(x)$ an increasing function (any cdf is increasing). Unrelated to $F(x)$, let $X$ be a r.v. that is uniformly distributed on the interval $[\phi-\xi,\phi+\xi]$. Note that $E(X) = \phi$.

If $F(x)$ is concave, by Jensen's inequality, we have
$$\int_{\phi-\xi}^{\phi+\xi} F(x) dx = E[F(X)] \le F[E(X)] = F (\phi)$$
Likewise, if $F(x)$ is convex, Jensen's inequality yields the opposite inequality.

This answer proves a weak inequality. If you prefer the strong inequality, a sufficient condition is that the function $F(x)$ is strictly concave.

Answer (score 0):

Without losing generality $\phi=0$.

You can write your inequality as
$$\frac{1}{2\xi}\int_{ -\xi}^{  \xi} (F(x)-F(0))dx $$
In the simple case when $F\in C^2$ we can say that $F(x) = F(0) + x F'(0) + x^2 F''(\zeta)/2$ for some $\zeta$ between $x$ and $0$, so 
$$\frac{1}{2\xi}\int_{-\xi}^{ \xi} (F(x)-F(0))dx  =  \frac{1}{2\xi}\int_{ -\xi}^{ \xi} \left(xF'(0) + \frac{x^2 F''(\zeta)}{2}\right)dx  = \frac{1}{2\xi}\int_{ -\xi}^{ \xi}   \frac{x^2 F''(\zeta)}{2} dx .$$
By passsing to the limit $\xi\to+0$, you can conclude that $F''(0)<0$ and hence your $F$ indeed must be concave.

By applying the same ideas you can extend this result to $C^1$ and (I think) derivable functions $F$; for the general case this method obviously fails.